# Pandas plot 2 series with different x values in same chart with distinct of x-values as xaxis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 2 panda series generated from a normalized `count_values()`.

s:

```
take    0.031110
like    0.039751
go      0.051504
buy     0.065330
get     0.113031
```

s2:

```
need    0.029009
like    0.037799
go      0.041609
buy     0.063512
get     0.108490
```

I want to plot these series in 1 bar chart. the axis index can be the distinct values of both s and s1. so example, i should have `['take','like','go','buy','get','need']`.

the y values of the bar plots should only have 1 yaxis.

I tried this:

```
ax = s.plot()
s2.plot(ax=ax)
```

And got this output:
[image]

its missing 'take' in the x-axis and i dont think the y values are right. `need` does not appear in s2 also but the double lines show there is.

I tried using bar plots, but only 1 bar plot appears:

[image]

What am i missing in my code?
 **Ideally, i should have 2 bars per word if the 2 words exist in s and s2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the default outer-join behaviour of `pd.concat([s, s2], axis=1)` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects)).

```
pd.concat([s, s2], axis=1).fillna(0).rename(columns={0: 's', 1: 's2'}).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Thats pretty smart! to do an outer join so all rows are present and fill empty values with zeros! thanks